# Conditional expectation identity

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Consider the example below (from Ross, *Introduction to Probability Models*, p. 104), with $X$ and $Y$ continuous random variables.

[image]

I found out that the following holds for this example:

$$E[X] = E[X\ |\ Y= E[Y]] $$

$$E[X] = 3,\ \ E[Y] = 1,\ \ E[X\ |\ Y = y] = 2 + y$$

Is this a coincidence (I am inclined to think so) or does the first identity hold somewhat more generally?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try 
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{2}{3}(x+2y) \quad 0\leq x,y \leq 1
$$
and see that in general it's not true. If you consider $X,Y$ discrete, $E[Y]$ may even be non part of the support of $Y$.